# Trying to find an element while iterating through a vector C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to programming, and i'm practicing programming and I am having trouble overcoming this problem.

I'm making a program where the user has to input a student roll number and then the value gets input into a function where the function iterates through the vector and checks if the roll number equals to any of the elements inside the vector

If not, it will just output "RN not found" and return to the main();

```
vector<int> rollNumbers = { 1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005 };

int CheckRollNumber(int rollNumberCheck) {
int i = 0;

for (auto& i : rollNumbers) {
    if (i == rollNumberCheck) {
        cout << "RN FOUND" << endl;
    }
    else if (i != rollNumberCheck)
        cout << "RN not found" endl;
        main();
}
return 0;
```

}

The function doesn't work, if I input "1000" it will return as "RN FOUND" but if I put any other roll number like 1001, 1002 or higher. It will return "RN not found".

Comment: Why not use [`std::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)? But the problem is calling `main()` inside the `for`-loop.

Comment: Firstly, calling `main()` is invalid in C++ (even though some implementations allow it, as yours apparently does).     Second, your code needs to check ALL elements of the vector before it can conclude "RN not found" - but your code reports "RN not found" on every loop iteration where a not-equal value found   (the recursion of `main()` just means it repeats the same checks it has already done, over and over, once any `i` is found that is not equal to `rollNumberCheck`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on not using an algorithm (suppose it's an exercise):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<int> rollNumbers = { 1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005 };

bool CheckRollNumber(int n, const std::vector<int>& rollNums) {
    for (const auto& i : rollNums) {
        if (i == n) {
            std::cout << "RN FOUND" << std::endl;
            return true;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "RN not found"  << std::endl; 
    return false; // None of the elements was == n
}
 
int main() {
    std::vector<int> nums  = { 1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005 };
    CheckRollNumber(1002, nums);
}
```

Otherwise:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
 
bool has_n(int n, const std::vector<int>& nums) {
    auto ret = std::find(nums.cbegin(), nums.cend(), n);
    bool result = ret != nums.cend();
    if (result)
        std::cout << "Found" << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "Not found" << '\n';
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> rollNumbers = { 1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005 };
    has_n(1005, rollNumbers);
}
```

The call to `main()` is bogus:

> A program shall contain a global function named main, which is the
> designated start of the program in hosted environment. - [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function)

Your loop printed `RN not found` each time loop iterated over the container and the current element was not equal to the one we looking.

Comment: Could you explain to me what const does in the for loop?

Comment: @YousefIbrahim it denotes that we are not intended to do any modification of the values of container elements, just read them out. In general, any time we want only to read, we should stick to `const`.

Comment: @YousefIbrahim Do you have any further questions? Any questions on the `<algorithm>` part?